# Show custom image size smaller in editor

Tags: images

I have a custom image size which editors should be able to use in their posts. I already managed for the custom size to show up in the add image dialogue, so that part is fine. 
On the destop version it will be showing as smaller versions (at about 230x230px), while for responsive they should expand to the full with (760x760px).

For convenient work in the WYSIWYG WordPress editor I would want to have the custom image sized images to show at a larger scale than they actually are, i.e. 230x230px or alike, so that they don’t fill up the edit screen. Is there a convenient way to tell WordPress to show a custom sized image on a smaller scale? Or is admin CSS the only way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if you just want to effect the way things look in a post/page text-editor, you can create a stylesheet for the Tiny MCE using add_editor_style: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editor_Style This way your CSS is only for the text-editor's content. Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah, that’s the way I meant with 'admin CSS' - but thanks a lot for your speedy response :).